# Dynamically position right corner arrow of the ActionBar Spinner based on length of displayed title

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-spinner

In the Google+ App, the position of the right corner arrow of the `ActionBar` `Spinner` adapts to the length of the current string showing. For example, the Spinner's length seems shorter when *Family* is picked versus when *Acquaintances* is picked.

What do I have to do to get the right corner arrow to position dynamically based on the title's length? My guess is that there's an attribute I can set in *styles.xml* that will do that for me.

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:AttributeHere">AttributeValue</item>
</style>
```

Here's the code I have in my MainActivity.java:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

// Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
SpinnerAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
        new String[] { "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "BB" });

// Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(dataAdapter, this);
```

Unlike in Google+, the position of my right corner arrow is always fixed. So if I choose from "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" to "BB" from the dropdown, the arrow doesn't move at all.

Comment: Have you figured out the way? Almost 4 years have passed..

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the code of android pure `Calendar`, in its adapter, `getView()` always returns the current item in `Calendar` so that the width of the `Spinner` is equal to the current item. Actually, the `Spinner` width in `ActionBar` is always calculated as the length of its longest item. `Calendar` does some special process here.