# Align spinner arrow to the right of the currently selected item

Tags: java, android, spinner

How can I align the `Spinner` "arrow" 0dp to the right of the current selected `Spinner` item?

By default, `Spinner` finds the longest `string`, and puts it to the right of that. So, how do I find the current `string` and place it to the right of that?

The code I'm using to implement the `Spinner`:

> ```
> ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter =
>             ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
>                     R.array.main_navigation_list, R.layout.spinner_text);
>
> spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
>
> mNavigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
> mNavigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
>
> mNavigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
> toolbar.addView(mNavigationSpinner);
> ```

[image]

Any ideas help! Thank you

---

This question is a duplicate that was never answered.
[Dynamically position right corner arrow of the ActionBar Spinner based on length of displayed title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874734/dynamically-position-right-corner-arrow-of-the-actionbar-spinner-based-on-length)

Comment: Hello, I had the same issue. My solution is to set match_parent to the Spinner.

Comment: Any news on this? :)